Why is Bxd5 a bad positional move?
After this move the module gives white a small edge. Why can it be considered a bad positional move for black? I'd like to know to improve my positional play.

https://ibb.co/fCJ6pFM
https://ibb.co/dWN9RZm

Please add the position in the body of the question for users who can't or don't want to follow links out of SE.

You lost one move to move your own knight and you gave your opponent two-bishop advantage. In fact, you should have tried to achieve your opponent's position, move the bishop f8-e7, not c8-e6.

In addition to magd:

The good bishop has been traded for a knight (and not a bad bishop!)
The white bishop pair at the moment largely stares at pawns.
Thus neither trading the bishop or the bishop pair is that
bad in this position. White has a solid space advantage due
to the trade, though, which I count higher. I would suggest
the following standard experiment:
Replace Be2 by a Ne2, identical advantage.
Replace Bc1 by a Nc1, tiny advantage.
Replace both B by N, tiny advantage.
Replace bad Bf8 by Nf8, identical advantage.

Evidently Bc1 is White's best minor piece.

That's your good bishop you just gave up (your central pawns are on the opposite colour square). Gives up the bishop pair for no reason and slightly improves White's pawns (more advanced).
